# Display deletable characters in a terminal (using libedit/editline or readline)

Tags: c, posix, readline, editline

I am currently using libedit for "readline"-functionallity, so far it works really well, but I would like to display characters (spaces) after the prompt which are deleteable by the user. Similiar to IPython:

[image: Ipython]

As you can see there are 4 additional characters (spaces) automatically added, which I can remove by pressing backspace, until I reach the prompt `...:`.

I would like to mimic this behaviour with libedit/editline and if there is no way to do this (e.g. using curses or the underlaying terminal function which libedit uses), I would switch to readline.

How is this possible to do, preferable with libedit/editline or readline.

Edit: I tried modifying `rl_line_buffer`, this didn't modify the display, only the value I get from `readline`.

Comment: There is nothing to the code, all it does is call `readline("prompt> ")` in a loop. It's basically the [example code of libedit](https://github.com/troglobit/editline/blob/master/examples/testit.c).

Comment: What about calling `rl_forced_update_display` after modifying `rl_line_buffer`?

Comment: This redraws the last prompt and the input, but doesn't display the contents of `rl_line_buffer`.